# How can we use Mapbox JS to filter unclassified raster using image service?

Tags: raster, mapbox-gl-js, filenet-image-services

I want to filter the unclassified raster using image services based on the Legend Value of Raster(Image Service)

I have tried the map.setFilter to filter the class value (Legend) of the raster using image service. But, it's not working properly.

Comment: Can you be more specific or provide an example?

Comment: @ToniBCN - We have an unclassified image service showing the legend value on a map using Mabox GL. created a slider to select the range of the legend value. Now, if the user selects a specific range of legend values, the legend that falls within that range should be rendered on the map. Please let me know if you require more clarification